# Oracle: What’s the difference between a permanent and a temporary data file?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Oracle: What’s the difference between a permanent and a temporary data file?

Answer (score 1):

A permanent table ( materialized table) is stored as a file in hard disks. The temporary table just lives in a transaction. In addition, a global temp table could be alive outside transaction, but not really stored.

Comment: '#' is a SQL Server syntax, this was asked with an Oracle flag. Your answer is correct for SQL Server, not for Oracle

Answer (score 1):

If by temporary, you mean a global temporary table, the contents are stored in the temporary tablespace (by default tempdb, but the default can be changed). The contents are isolated by session, and go away when the session terminates. You can create with "on commit delete rows" or "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS", which do exactly what they say. Temporary tables are useful for holding large amounts of data during processing where the contents will not be used in the future. While they do still generate quantities of undo log, they generate much less redo logs, and therefore require somewhat less database resources than using a permanent table for the same purpose.

Because the data is isolated by session, it simplifies coding for concurrent activity, you don't need to worry about one session stomping on another session's data.

Answer (score 0):

In short permanent table space used to store permanent schema data, temporary table space used for intermediate data which occurs while DB working for example result sets sorting grouping ordering  etc.